# Seeking text describing the Mantel-Haenszel test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

Seeking a textbook or other publication describing the Mantel-Haenszel test of a $2 \times 2 \times r$ table that provides at least one numeric example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Rao, Miller, Rao, eds. Handbook of Statistics, vol 27](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444528016), p. 604, or [Read et al., eds. Encyclopedia of Statistical Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471150444).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the example provided in the HoS27 is about meta-analysis.

Comment: Is a meta-analysis M-H analysis different from a 2x2xR M-H analysis?  The book costs over $200.  Is there really a numeric example there, including the raw data (i.e., cell counts).  Thanks.

Comment: In both of the books I cited, the relevant sections are only 3-4 pages long. You can probably find them in a good university library close to you; try worldcat.org.

Comment: It seems there are 15 volumes of this title.  Is it in this one: Encyclopedia of statistical sciences 7. Lineo-normal distribution to Mixtures of normal distributions, estimation of

Comment: Found it online (via a university library). Thanks again!